# Objective-C : pulling value out of NSString

Tags: objective-c, parsing

I have a bunch of NSStrings like this....

```
{
     "score" = 15;
     "serial" = 8;
}
```

What is the best way to extract the values out of this string using "id" and "score"?

Answer (score 0):

These are property lists in text format. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072308/parse-plist-nsstring-into-nsdictionary/1072365#1072365) for how to parse them. You'll get a `NSDictionary` from which you can pull the values as `NSNumber`s.