# Instance variable not retaining value in iOS application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, scope, instance-variables

I have declared this ivar in my

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

{   
NSArray *sortedCountries;       
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *sortedCountries;

@end
```

In ViewController.m, sortedCountries does it's job in  `-(void)ViewDidLoad{}` by storing the result of a sorted .plist.

When

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {}
```

is called below, sortedCountries returns `(null)`

Why doesn't the value of sortedCountries remain? I added a `retain` in the first function... I think I am missing a fundamental Objective-C tenant here.

ViewController.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@implementation FirstViewController

@synthesize sortedCountries;

-(void)viewDidLoad  {

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"countries" ofType:@"plist"];  
NSArray *countries = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES] autorelease];
NSArray *sortedCountries = [[countries sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]]retain];

}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return 236; 
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSDictionary *country = [sortedCountries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"countryDictionary is: %@",country);
NSString *countryName = [country objectForKey:@"name"];
NSLog(@"countryName is : %@", countryName);

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell =
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

}

cell.textLabel.text = countryName;
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are re-declaring `sortedCountries` as a local variable in `viewDidLoad`. Use:

```
sortedCountries = ...
```

instead (notice no `NSArray *`). In the code you are using now, `sortedCountries` would be populated in `viewDidLoad`, but accessible **only** in `viewDidLoad`. You were creating a new variable with the same name instead of setting the class property.

Answer (score 6):

```
NSArray *sortedCountries = [[countries sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]]retain];
```

to

```
self.sortedCountries = [countries sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];
```