# How do I get values from a tiered .plist?

Tags: ios, dictionary, tree, plist

> I've already looked at [Parse Plist (NSString) into NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072308/parse-plist-nsstring-into-nsdictionary) and deemed it to be **not a duplicate**, as that question and its answer do not address my concerns.

---

I have a `.plist` file in the file system structured like this:

[image: Root > My App > Side Panel > Items > Price]

The source code of this `.plist` file looks like this:

```
{
    "My App" = {
        "Side Panel" = {
            Items = {
                Price = "#123ABC";
            };
        };
    };
}
```

I know how to get an item in the `Root` like this:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSString value = [dict objectForKey:@"key"]);
```

But what if the structure is like mine, with tiered dictionaries? **How do I get the value of `Price`?**

I would like to do this all in one method, ideally like this:

Calling

```
NSString *hexString = [self getColorForKey:@"My App.Side Panel.Items.Price"];
```

Definition

```
- (NSString *) getColorForKey: (NSString *)key
{
    NSArray *path = [key componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    NSDictionary *colors = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Colors" ofType:@"plist"]];
    NSString *color = @"#FFFFFF"; // white is our backup

    // What do I put here to get the color?

    return color;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse Plist (NSString) into NSDictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072308/parse-plist-nsstring-into-nsdictionary)

Comment: @LouisTur That deals with one that's parsed from a String in memory, and I don't see how it or its answers applies to my issue.

Comment: @LouisTur yeah, that answer doesn't help me at all. Could you elaborate on how you think it's related? Perhaps knowing more about your thought process would help.

Comment: Are you asking how to get to a subnode in an `NSDictionary`? It's conceptually the same as getting the root node, `NSString *price = dict[@"Root"][@"MyApp"][@"Side Panel"][@"Items"][@"Price"]`. Using KVO is also a possibility. Traversing a dictionary is a fundamental concept, regardless of your data source, I would of done a quick search on the topic before posting. But this may help: http://appventure.me/2011/12/07/fast-nsdictionary-traversal-in-objective-c/

Comment: @LouisTur I've added an example case of how I want to do this. Does this help you understand my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution that worked for me:

```
+ (NSString*) getHexColorForKey:(NSString*)key
{
    NSArray *path = [key componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    NSDictionary *colors = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Colors" ofType:@"plist"]];
    NSString *color = @"#FFFFFF";
    for (NSString *location in path) {
        NSObject *subdict = colors[location];
        if ([subdict isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        {
            color = (NSString*)subdict;
            break;
        }
        else if ([subdict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        {
            colors = (NSDictionary*)subdict; // if it's a dictinoary, our color may be inside it
        }
        else
        {
            [SilverLog level:SilverLogLevelError message:@"Unexpected type of dictinoary entry: %@", [subdict class]];
            return color;
        }
    }
    return color;
}
```

where `key` is an `NSString` that matches `/^[^.]+(\.[^.]+)*$/`, meaning it looks like my targeted `@"My App.Side Panel.Items.Price"`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I understand what you're looking to accomplish; thank you for the clarification. I will however add that the resources and advice I have written do provide the necessary information resolve your problem.

That said, the following gets your dictionary:

```
NSURL *plistURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Info" withExtension:@"plist"];
NSData *plistData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:plistURL];
NSDictionary *tieredPlistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:plistData 
                                                                          options:kCFPropertyListImmutable 
                                                                           format:NULL 
                                                                            error:nil];
```

Then, if we're interested in the information contained in `Items`

```
NSDictionary *allItemsDictionary = tieredPlistData[@"My App"][@"Side Panel"][@"Items"];
```

Assuming that `Items` will contain a number of objects, you could use

```
NSArray *keys = [allItems allKeys];
for(NSString *key in keys){
    NSString *colorValue = allItemsDictionary[key];
    // do something with said color value and key
}
```

Or, if there is a single value you need, then just reference that key

```
NSString *colorForPriceText = allItemsDictionary[@"Price"];
```

But a few tips:

- It's generally considered a better idea to keep frequently accessed values in code instead of a plist/file that is loaded at runtime.
- That said, you wouldn't put your call to load from `NSBundle` in the same method you would use to query a specific value. In your example, every time you need a color, you end up re-accessing `NSBundle` and pile on unneeded memory allocations. One method would load the plist into an iVar `NSDictionary` and then that `NSDictionary` would be used separately by another method.

Comment: Does that work if there are two values called price? Say, `My App.Side Panel.Items.Price` and `My App.Printout.Items.Price`?

Comment: Well, yes and no.. it doesn't matter that they are the same key because the path to get to them are different -- one would be `plist[@"My App"][@"Side Panel"]...` and the other would be `plist[@"My App"][@"Printout"]...`. But the code currently cannot get to the second one because it hard codes the base path as `allItemsDictionary = tieredPlistData[@"My App"][@"Side Panel"][@"Items"]`

Comment: I mean your second solution: `NSString *colorForPriceText = allItemsDictionary[@"Price"];`