# How to read Plist file from server and directly use it without creating local file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3

I'm working on a project and I have some setting on the server which I got through the Plist file and I want to read this Plist file without creating any local copy.

Need to store this setting in the dictionary, not in the local Plist file.

any idea how can we do this?

**Sample Plist like below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>New item</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>value</key>
            <string>Data1</string>
            <key>key</key>
            <string>Tab1</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>value</key>
            <string>Data2</string>
            <key>key</key>
            <string>Tab2</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Let me know if required more detail on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072308/parse-plist-nsstring-into-nsdictionary for an Objective-C solution

Comment: Yes for ObjectiveC its fine but how can we do same in Swift3 any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost the same like loading and parsing JSON. Instead of `JSONSerialization` use `PropertyListSerialization`.

```
let urlString = "http://server.com/api"

let url = URL(string: urlString)
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!) { data, _, error in
  if let error = error { print(error); return } 
  do {         
      let plistDictionary = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data!, format: nil) as! [String:Any]
      print(plistDictionary)
  } catch {
      print(error)
  }
}.resume()
```

Comment: great Let me try it out. Thanks for your quick answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [NSPropertyListSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspropertylistserialization) class to parse your `Data` from response to `Dictionary`.

```
let url:URL = URL(string: "")! // URL to fetch plist

let urlSession:URLSession = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)

urlSession.dataTask(with: url) { (data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?) in

guard let data = data else {
    return
}

let plistDict = try? PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options:.mutableContainers, format: nil)

guard let dict = plistDict else {
    print("Error in parsing")
    return
}

print(dict)

}.resume()
```